# App Engine python27 urlfetch error: "[Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to switch my app engine app from python 2.5 to 2.7 and urlfetch.fetch() just doesn't want to work (on the dev server at least; I haven't deployed it yet).  If I do something as simple as:

```
file = urlfetch.fetch(url="http://www.google.com")
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\workspace\DjangoServer\src\mycode.py", line 167, in request
    file = urlfetch.fetch(url="http://www.google.com")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 264, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 366, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Searching the internet has suggested it might be a firewall or proxy issue, but I turned off the firewall and I'm not behind a proxy.

This works fine in the python 2.5 dev server, but not the python 2.7 dev server.  If I open a python 2.7 console and manually run`socket.getaddrinfo("www.google.com", 80)` it works there as well.

Any ideas? Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: You're on the latest version of the SDK, 1.6.0?

Comment: Also, would you ping localhost and confirm that it resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 1.6 SDK and pinging localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1.  My hosts file is also empty. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: OK. FWIW, your test works for me with all the same versions.

Comment: Does it happen with other domains, or just google.com?

Comment: Every domain.  My actual use case is with the facebook python sdk, so I'm trying to access "https://graph.facebook.com/..." , but I figured www.google.com was a simpler example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have been able to reproduce this issue and after a lot of going back and forth in git from a version that was working to a version that was not working I found that (at least in my case) the problem was in django-nonrel (because I updated all at once: django-nonrel and appengine).

So, please do the following: edit djangoappengine/settings_base.py and change

```
try:
    from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
except ImportError:
    from .boot import setup_env
    setup_env()

from djangoappengine.utils import on_production_server, have_appserver
```

to:

```
from djangoappengine.utils import on_production_server, have_appserver
if not on_production_server:
    from .boot import setup_env
    setup_env()
```

The real issue seems to be that in a previous version of django-nonrel, the import was actually written as: **from google.appengine.api import api_proxy_stub_map** (which was never found and the setup_env() was always called), so, when the import was fixed, the setup_env() was no longer called (which in my case made the error appear).

A 2nd note is that for some reason this was only happening when running inside of Eclipse/PyDev and it did work on the command line (although the environment variables seemed the same for me, so, I'm unsure why running from inside java actually made a difference).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the error for me :( I'm using PyCharm. Thanks anyways.